# How to access "lang" attribute to create ng-class expression?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I want to apply a `css` class only if the `lang` attribute resolves to `de` in `angularjs`. My `div` looks like:

```
<div lang="de" ng-class="{ 'myDEclass' : lang === 'de' }">
```

How can I get the value of the `lang` attribute to get a valid expression the angular way?

Comment: if you have a `$scope.lang = "de";` it will resolve to true

Comment: The information does not come from my current view controller, but from my root application controller while initialization

Comment: then put it as a property on your `$rootScope` object, it will also work as `$root.lang == ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 'global' variables to your `$rootScope` object to make it available everywhere:

```
angular.module("myModule")
    .config(function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.lang = "de";
    });
```

then in your view (note the $root):

```
<div lang="de" ng-class="{ 'myDEclass' : $root.lang === 'de' }">
```

Comment: Thank you. It was not clear to me, how to access $rootScope.xxx variable with $root.xxx

Answer (score 0):

you forget the { } in the ng-class

```
    <div lang="de" ng-class="{ 'myDEclass' : lang === 'de' }">
```

Comment: Yes of course. I will adapt this. But this question is more theoretical actually.